# 21.10 Wayland - Chrome context menu no contrast

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

My Chrome context menus have very low contrast, which makes it hard to select a context menu items via the keyboard (using the mouse you can see where the pointer is).

You can (barely) see in the picture below that the "Reload" item is selected: it's ever so slightly darker text and ever so slightly shaded.

Other applications (LibreOffice Writer, Thunderbird) do not have this issue, pretty high contrast for the selected item.

Changing the Chrome theme and Ubuntu appearance -> windows colors change various other window widget colors, but not the selected context menu item. Anybody else have this? Any ideas of where else it can be set?

[image]